# Converting event handler from C# to C++/CLI

Tags: events, c++-cli

I have a C# event handler that I would like to C++/CLI, but I have been unable to find any similar handles online. I would like to keep the structure somewhat similar if possible. Is there any documentation or similar functionaly it in C++/CLI?

Here is the C# event:

```
private void SubEvent<TEvent, TPayload>(SubscriptionToken token, Action<TPayload> payload, ThreadOption threadOption, bool foo)
        where TEvent : PubSubEvent<TPayload>, new()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in that method signature that doesn't have a direct equivalent in C++/CLI. You should be able to do the exact same thing in C++/CLI as you're doing in C#.

```
private:
    generic<typename TEvent, typename TPayload> where TEvent : PubSubEvent<TPayload>, gcnew()
    void SubEvent(SubscriptionToken^ token, Action<TPayload>^ payload, ThreadOption threadOption, bool foo)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: Wow, I had it returning void and that is what threw me off. Thanks for the easy fix.